# ASCIIDOC PDF Generation Footnote renders in the text and not to end of page

Tags: pdf-generation, asciidoc, footnotes

my first question here *excited*

in my ASCIIDOC code I have

```
Big Name{wj}footnote:[Big because X] is found.
```

This is perfectly rendered to the end of the (one an long) page generating html.

```
Big Name⁠ [1] is found. 

<a lot of other text till the end of the one long html page>

--
1. Big because X
```

But generating PDF it renders into the text:

```
Big Name⁠ [1: Big because X] is found.
```

Why the PDF-generation is dfferent? 
How can I control the type of rendering during PDF generation?

I use

```
asciidoctor sample.adoc
asciidoctor -r asciidoctor-pdf -b pdf sample.adoc
```

with

```
asciidoctor -v
Asciidoctor 1.5.4 [http://asciidoctor.org]
Runtime Environment (ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21) [x86_64-linux-gnu]) (lc:UTF-8 fs:UTF-8 in:- ex:UTF-8)
```

Comment: Asciidoctor PDF 1.5.0.alpha.16 using Asciidoctor 1.5.4

Comment: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/issues/85   

This shows a bounty of 75$ and that this is still an open question :-(

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is a bug in asciidoctor-pdf (see https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/issues/73).

However, I'm able to generate footnotes (and other book-related structures) with asciidoctor-fopub (see https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-fopub).

So after downloading the `fopub`, you have first to convert your `adoc` to `xml` and then convert the `xml` to `pdf`.

so commands will be something similar to this:

```
asciidoctor -b docbook -a data-uri! your_document.adoc
/path/to/fopub your_document.xml
```